# WCF not returning message properly to client

Tags: .net, wcf

```
  public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
           
            
        }
```

I am getting my result in the BeforeSendReply -> reply, but it is not reaching in the client, client is empty, Can you anybody help here? No exception, oin the client side the reply expecting object returning null. Can anyone hepl to where to look into to find this issue

Comment: Hi! There really is not enough information for us to help you. This could be anything from a typo to a bigger problem in wcf reference. Like I said anything. Please add more information to the question, how do you return (set) the object, how is the call made etc etc. By the way, I would change the method to actually return the Message (not void) instead of ref-parameter which in my mind is just bad practice.

Comment: You can start by checking your endpoint and bindings to see if the server-side matches the client-side. Also try [MSMQ queue messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-exchange-messages-with-wcf-endpoints-and-message-queuing-applications). Of course it would be nice to have more details.